# Every other list divider is thicker than specified

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Can't seem to solve the problem i'm having. As you can see from the image provided the list divider in the middle is thicker than the other two. Anyone know how i can solve this?

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/dividerColor"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <!-- Id -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

    <!-- Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/id"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/id"/>

    <!-- Location -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/id"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: List Divider]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of your listview's listitems is null causing two dividers to appear stacked.

Comment: I'm not completely sure but i don't think that's it. It appears to be changing when i scroll. A divider that was once thick turns normal depending on where it is. Strange.